# Excel VBA: Copy and paste selection based off row and column headers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will format and create a weekly report.
It has five columns that need to be moved: Key, Summary, Created, Status, Fix Version/s.

I need to copy a selection that starts at Row 2 in the Key column and ends at the last row in the Fix Version/s column that will then be pasted into a sheet called "Priority Issues". I am unsure how to code this specific selection.

I need to store the last row in a variable, as the last row may change from week to week. In essence, I am looking for code that allows me to make a selection from the intersection of row 2 and the Key column to the intersection of the last row and the Fix Version/s column, but am unsure how to do that.

```
Function FindCol(toFind As String) As Range
Dim Rtn As Range
Set Rtn = Rows(1).Find(What:=toFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set FindCol = Rtn
End Function

Sub Move_Severity()
Dim Severity As Range
Dim Key As Range
Dim Fix_Version As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Severity = FindCol("Severity")
Set Key = FindCol("Key")
Set Fix_Version = FindCol("Fix Version/s")
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Severity.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'This is where I am running into problems
Range(Cells(2, Key), Cells(LastRow, Fix_Version)).Copy
Sheets("Priority Issues").Range("A2").Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Fix_Version As Range` then you do `Cells(LastRow, Fix_Version)` but `cells` require a number not range. I presume the function works properly? Edit: you have 2 options, change function to return col number or set your variables to long and do `FindCol("Key").column`.

Comment: For `FindCol`, do you not need this instead? `Set FindCol = Rtn.Column`?

Comment: Batman, it returns a range. Edit: but yes, makes more sense to return the col number^^

Comment: I kept forgetting .column, as soon as I figured that out the rest was easy. Rookie mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Move_Severity()
Dim Severity As Range
Dim Key As Range
Dim Fix_Version As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Severity = FindCol("Severity")
Set Key = FindCol("Key")
Set Fix_Version = FindCol("Fix Version/s")

With ActiveSheet '<~~ change active sheet reference to whatever must it be 
    .Range(.Cells(2, Key.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Severity.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Priority Issues").Range("A2")
End With

End Sub
```

should you only need to paste values then change that `With-End With` part to

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range(.Cells(2, Key.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Severity.Column).End(xlUp))
        Sheets("Priority Issues").Range("A2").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

which is much faster

Comment: Oh snap. Smarter than my idea^^

Comment: @findwindow thanks since that is quite hard to ever happen

Comment: Wait what :o Pretty sure you mean the other way around^^

Comment: @findwindow not at all, I confirm what I wrote :-)

Comment: Dat flattery. Well, I already upvoted so have... an imaginary cookie XD